# Can we change Target Oracle Database version in sratch editor?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-migration

I am trying to migrate source code into different versions of Oracle depending on my requirement. Currently I know Oralce 12c version supports IDENTITY column, but when I am trying to convert a table with IDENTITY column, scratch editor is converting it into SEQUENCE and Triggers.
If any option is present using sdcli.exe also, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Scratch, but can't you just use a normal column with a sequence as default value?
That is basically what Oracle creates under the covers when you use an identity column.

Some background:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1

Comment: Actually that was just a example, I am looking for a generic thing in which according Target Oracle database version, scratch editor converts the code.